# How to get reference to the function or variable with the same name in Kotlin?

Tags: function, kotlin, variables, reference, ambiguity

The problem is when I try to get the reference to `testVar` variable in Kotlin, ambiguity occurs if I have a function with the same name as the variable. Is there a solution for this?

```
class TestClassBuilder {

    lateinit var mainVar: String
    lateinit var testVar: String

    fun mainVar(mainVar: String) = apply {
        this.mainVar = mainVar
    }

    fun testVar(testVar: String) = apply {
        this.testVar = testVar
    }
    
    fun build() {
        if (!::testVar.isInitialized) {
            testVar = mainVar.substring(0, 5)
        }
        // ...
    }
}
```

I've tried to rename variable and, of course, it worked, but I'd like to know if there is a better solution.

Comment: In the vast majority of cases, if you’re having to use `isInitialized` defensively, you shouldn’t be using `lateinit` in the first place. Usually you should be using a nullable type instead, but in this case you could be using a lazy delegate.

Comment: The situation of a property and a function having the same name never happens if you follow naming conventions. Functions should start with verbs and properties should not.

Comment: Lazy delegate can't be applied to the var property. If I make it val, than I won't be able to change the value via `breakParticle` function.
And as for naming conventions, I always thought that for Builder pattern it's ok to name functions with variable names, omitting `set` prefix.

Comment: @СергейАндриенко The builder pattern isn't used much in Kotlin, as you can do about the same using `apply{…}`.  Also, it's quite common for builders to use function names along the lines of `withProperty()`, which have no ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do anything with this problem, but you don't need it. If you use Kotlin properties it will generate setters for you.

First of all, please check how properties work - [link](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/properties.html)

Then you use plain properties:

```
class TestClassBuilder {
    lateinit var mainVar: String
    lateinit var testVar: String

    fun build() {
        if (!::testVar.isInitialized) {
            testVar = mainVar.substring(0, 5)
        }
    }
}

fun main() {
    val builder = TestClassBuilder()
    builder.mainVar = "some text"
}
```

And here is how you can use setters from Java:

```
public class C {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestClassBuilder t = new TestClassBuilder();
        t.mainVar = "some text"; // variant 1
        t.setMainVar("another text"); // variant 2
    }
}
```

Also you can add visibility modifiers for getters and setters or even custom logic:

```
var testVar: String = ""
    set(value) {
        field = if (value.startsWith("abc")) {
            value.removePrefix("abc")
        } else value
    }
```